# c++ Replace character of char pointer with char pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, char-pointer

I'm having problemes with a function which should replace every character *c* in the given char array *src* with the char array *text*.

first I calculate the length of the return value. Then I insert the correct chars. At least thats what i try.

The problem is I am having unexpected behaviour at the return value. sometimes it replaces only the first matching letter. sometimes is is replacing every an adding one cryptic letter.

```
char *myreplace(const char *src, char c, const char *text){
    int mylength=0;
    for(int i=0; src[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(src[i] == c)
            for(int j=0; text[j] != '\0'; j++){
                ++mylength;
            }
        else
            ++mylength;
    }

    char *newtext=new char[mylength+1];

    int x=0;
    for(int i=0; src[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(src[i] == c)
            for(int j=0; text[j] != '\0'; j++){
                newtext[i+x] = text[j];
                ++x;
            }
        else
            newtext[i+x]=src[i];

    }
    return newtext;
}
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include details on what the problem is. (One issue is that you don't add the terminating nul character to the end of `newtext`.)

Comment: can you tell me what else is a problem?

Comment: This is tagged as C but `char *newtext=new char[mylength+1];` is C++. Are you using the right compiler?

Answer (score 1):

When you replace one character with your replacement string, you effectively double increment (both `i` and `x`), resulting in skipping one character for each replaced instance and writing past the end of the allocated buffer.

Let's look at an example: `src` is "abc", `text` is "d", and `ch` is 'a'.

When we replace the first character, we write the `d` to `newtext` and increment `x`. The next time thru the loop, we write the second source character ('b') to `newtext[i+x]`, or `newtext[2]` when it should go to `newtext[1]`.

The simplest fix is to decrement `x` by 1 after copying in the replacement string.

You're also not writing the terminating nul character `'\0'` to the end of your `newtext` string.  (Add `nexttext[x+i] = 0;` before the return.)